# What does it mean by "Through" in Hebrews 1:2

Tags: jesus, hebrews

> **[Hebrews 1:1-3](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=heb+1%3A1-3&version=CEB)** (CEB)
>
> 1 In the past, God spoke through the prophets to our ancestors in many times and many ways. <sup>**2**</sup> In these final days, though, he spoke to us through a Son. God made his Son the heir of everything and created the world **through him**. <sup>**3**</sup> The Son is the light of God’s glory and the imprint of God’s being. He maintains everything with his powerful message. After he carried out the cleansing of people from their sins, he sat down at the right side of the highest majesty.

I'm just confused when it says that God created the world through Jesus. God didn't need Jesus to create the world.

Comment: You're right that God didn't **need** Jesus to create the world. But the verse doesn't say he needed to, just that he did! So why are you confused?

Answer (score -1):

Your statements that follow the verses suggest that you disagree with the idea that Jesus is God--"God didn't need Jesus to create the world."  The actual point of the Hebrews 1, especially Heb. 1:1-3 is to affirm that Jesus is better than the angels  because He is God.  The angels of God are to worship Him (Heb. 1:6).

Skipping over the detailed statements in Hebrews 1:2-3 and jumping down to the heart of the issue.  Is Jesus equal with God and therefore worthy of worship as the one true God? In Hebrews 1:6 the writer makes two statements.

> > Hebrews 1:6
> >     6 And again, when he bringeth in the firstbegotten into the world, he saith, And let all the angels of God worship him.

Many commentators have pointed to the first point as a reference to the second coming of Christ. When the Father has made the decision, that it is time for the Son to return to the earth.  The decision to return is in the Father's hands alone (Matthew 24:36).  The writer then quotes from the Septuagint (Psalm 96:7 in the LXX and Psalm 97:7 in the Hebrew and English Bibles), which has the phrase προσκυνήσατε αὐτῷ, πάντες οἱ ἄγγελοι αὐτοῦ (let all the angels worship him." Psalm 97 is about the appearance of the LORD (יְהוָ֑ה) the sacred name of God in the Old Testament (Yahweh or Jehovah depending on how you pronounce it). The heavens melt at "the presence of the Lord of the whole earth (Ps. 97:5).  The heaven declare his righteousness, and all the people see his glory (Ps. 97:6).  The pronoun "his" must be linked back to the LORD in verse 5 as no other person has been identified in verse 6.  Then in Psalm 97:7, the writer says that all those who serve graven images will be confounded when the LORD appears on the earth.  Then he ends with the statement that all the angels are to worship him.  Again the "him" in verse 7 points back to the sacred name of God, the LORD or Jehovah Himself.

This means that Jesus is better than the angels because He will be worshiped by those same angels, the angels who will worship Jehovah. Therefore the writer to the Hebrews equates Jesus with the sacred name of God in the Old Testament and as the object of worship.  This means that the worship and devotion that is due to the sacred name of God is to be directed at Jesus.

**The difficulty is not with what the text says it is with what it says about Jesus**

Answer (score -1):

The whole point of Heb 1 is that Jesus is both God and indispensable to everything.  More than this, Heb 1:3 and Col 1:15-18 also tells us that Jesus not only created all thing, but further, in Him all things are "sustained" or "hold together", suggesting that Jesus maintains the existence of the everything as well.

Heb 1:8 also declares Jesus "God" by God (the Father) as well.  Heb 1:10-12 quotes Ps 102:25-27 in the Septuagint.  The interesting matter here is the Greek use of the word "Lord" (Gr: kyrios) to translate the Hebrew Tetragrammaton YHWH often translated as Yaweh or Jehovah.  That is, this passage describes Jesus as Jehovah-God almighty.

It would be difficult (in fact impossible) to craft a passage that is any less ambiguous about the deity and unparalleled majesty of Jesus, His creativity and absolute authority.

Answer (score -2):

Much damage has been done by so-called *translators* using words that have no place in the text.

God did not make the world or universe through Jesus, He made the ‘ages’.

Insisting on reading world or universe creates great disharmony with remaining scripture.

How God could make these things through Jesus, when Jesus wasn’t born yet is bewildering. John writes, ‘in the beginning was the logos’, not Jesus. If we insist on placing Jesus, ‘in the beginning’, we are not accepting what has been inspired by God, but some other source.

There is no verse placing Jesus ‘in the beginning’ anywhere! Approx 4 bc Jesus was born of Mary fulfilling many prophecies.

**What does it mean by “Through” in Hebrews?**

As Jesus was part of God’s plan from the beginning, nothing was intended to reach the fullness of God’s creative action by itself.

Man is only ‘made in God’s image’ in Jesus. On his own, certainly after the so-called fall, man was anything but in God’s image. Jesus called out the Jews saying their father was the devil - meaning, figuratively, they were not following after God’s image as intended. Indeed as has been pointed out by Paul, we are *not capable* of choosing God on our own.

> You belong to your father, the devil, and you want to carry out your father's desires John 8:44

> For we are God’s workmanship, *created in Christ* Jesus to do good works, *which God prepared in advance* as our way of life Eph 2:10

> *But now* in Christ Jesus *you who once were far away have been brought near* through the blood of Christ Eph 2:13

> put on the new self who is being renewed to a true knowledge according to the image of the One who created him Col 3:10

> The Son is the image of the invisible God, the firstborn over all creation. Col 1:15

Certainly we are not remotely in God’s image alone, but *only in and through Christ*.